# Swagger UI: HTTP Content-type "application/json" causes "Unable to Load SwaggerUI"

Tags: content-type, swagger-ui

I have a very strange behaviour with Swagger UI v2.1.4:

When I return, from my server, my JSON document with the HTTP Content-type header "text/html", everything is fine in Swagger UI.

**But when I return the same JSON document with the HTTP Content-type header "application/json", I get a "Unable to Load SwaggerUI" error in the console.**

(And then in Swagger UI I have the common error message: "Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.".)

I have carefully checked all the details of the two HTTP responses (the working one and the failing one), and that's the only difference.

That's a pity since setting this "application/json" Content-type helps me debugging my Swagger file (because it is then displayed correctly in browsers when accessed directly).

Does anyone have an idea about how to make this "application/json" Content-type work with Swagger UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by simply **removing the Content-type HTTP header**: it makes my browser and my Swagger UI both happy. But I don't know if this is the most correct way to solve this problem…

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I did this in the Python Tornado server which I used for serving the Swagger JSON document. So you have to do so in the HTTP server that serves your file.